# How do you write decorators for both async and sync functions with readable signature?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, decorator, synchronous

Let's say I have a logging decorator:

```js
interface IOptions<FuncType extends (...args: any[]) => any> {
  onStart: string | ((...args: Parameters<FuncType>) => string);
  onFinish?: string | ((value: ReturnType<FuncType>) => string);
}

export function loggedFunction<FuncType extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  options: IOptions<FuncType>,
  func: FuncType
) {
  const { onStart, onFinish } = options;

  function logged(...args: Parameters<FuncType>) {
    const startLog = typeof onStart === "string" ? onStart : onStart(...args);
    console.log(startLog);

    const result = func(...args);

    if (onFinish) {
      const finishLog =
        typeof onFinish === "string" ? onFinish : onFinish(result);
      console.log(finishLog);
    }

    return result;
  }

  return logged;
}
```

While it does need to interact with the return value, it shouldn't change the signature of the passed function.
The solutions I thought so far:

- Write two functions: async and a sync one with exact body but a different return call and conditionally return one.
- Write a functional exression and conditionally assign sync/async lambda to it.

The second way at least doesn't create an extra function, but both require basically duplicating 95% of the logic. It might not look bad in this particular example, but I am sure it will not work well for more complex decorators (especially the ones which do change the signature).
So is there a way to write it as single logic only branching on sync/async check?
**EDIT**: the playground link showing [it breaks on async function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkAOZgHsQDOAPAGICuICAKgJ6YoQAekIAJgcgBQB0vcUAcwIAuZHBA0A2gF0AlMgC8APjESVAbwCwAKGTJ8AZTD8wogmCigByAD5cefQSOQAFfnAC2ESFGLlKtPRK8srI5pYgArIA3Dp6+CSgwAQAFgD8ZhZWtvYAbnAANmQQogBK3mRQIIEQpBTUdBDBiirhVjE6AL46OjD1OPjIBbgCAhCs-ggDIHUBjchMLOxcvNz8QqLiUnItqjRKnHH62HiEohgn+H71NUoANEd9lKKTNTryWrrICFdgyOr6EBGEx3QGJEDJFLITqKY7TAixbSPfqnIYjMasBxrJyiNxQTzeaDXOZBWRlCpVGqzBpBT56PQ-Qh-cwmAAyI1hYEauBggOBUD+CiFyAARG1IiLkGk+cYBchRIZZWAsesCB0vgyrrgChBuMMBJwWQL2VFEUdNUzkFAIAQyAVBcgnggVU51ebkMBeZwEklUh93RbzI7fSkTYoA-SufQeWCQ4phWKshKpbGIal5anIZxrbb7er6fTGQRtbr9ZwYCGTfn6d0kRqrRSQA3c2BEXpa0drWBKk39RjER3tEXmTRKJNYX3xpNppw6TKTJx8kUbf7612e8gAAYGUcID0gTBkP5L4rOAAk6gAUgZ0AA5bjigSemiLwqn2SdTdHToPL4+tMpN6R6HmAq4FuuVRbjulD6MBR6iBe153g+SZPjAL64HBoGft+XSgq+y7OCAZAeAARtAMghBonaNsgJ42twABWuCgJwIp3CKshdFxdbDmIBC7uOChoqMU4ovgs5HIqC70Wq-zuhBTabgAggJMGgCBdFvjaCFXje96Ps+BHvjhXw-lJIDglmmFgCBYH0opW6qbusG2fByCIfpKERGhGFYR+X5mXh-G7sZOnIMRZEUTsoRzo5slMSxIBsRxPGdDxOhqQgkycJIACMdwAEx3AAzHIZraJwcBZZwVHyV81WCfUuUFcVZVpbItVAA).

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with this implementation?

Comment: The async signature get changed into a sync one and `onFinish()` not working properly.

Comment: Not working properly how? Are you getting a promise in the onFinish callback? Do you have a playground to demonstrate the issue? It's unclear what you mean by "changed into a sync one".

Comment: Added playground link to the question because it's too big for a comment.

Comment: Use https://tsplay.dev/ in the future to shorten playground links.

Comment: Right, you probably have to check if the function is async: https://tsplay.dev/W4n3AN

Comment: That was exactly the problem I was talking about: it creates 2 functions (which are basically carbon copies with different syntax) but uses only one of them.
Also the signature looks like this:`function loggedFunction<FuncType extends (...args: any[]) => any>(options: IOptions<FuncType>, func: FuncType): ((...args: Parameters<FuncType>) => Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<FuncType>>>) | ((...args: Parameters<FuncType>) => ReturnType<FuncType>)`

Comment: Oh I see...  Annotate the return type as `FuncType`, and cast the return: https://tsplay.dev/wQ39Zm

Comment: Your async check doesn't work for promise-returning functions: tsplay.dev/wXqG8N . Also I remembered generators is a thing and, as expected, they also don't work with the current implementation. Moreover they lose their signature when decorated.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator will look like this:

```js
interface IOptions<ArgsType extends any[], OutputType> {
  onStart: string | ((...args: ArgsType) => string);
  onFinish?: string | ((value: OutputType) => string);
}

function loggedFunction<ArgType extends any[], OutputType>(
  options: IOptions<ArgType, OutputType>,
  func: (...args: ArgType) => Promise<OutputType> | OutputType
): typeof func {
  const { onStart, onFinish } = options;

  function logged(...args: Parameters<typeof func>): ReturnType<typeof func> {
    const startLog = typeof onStart === "string" ? onStart : onStart(...args);
    console.log(startLog);

    const result = func(...args);

    if (onFinish) {
      if (result instanceof Promise) {
        return result.then((value) => {
          const finishLog =
            typeof onFinish === "string" ? onFinish : onFinish(value);
          console.log(finishLog);

          return value;
        });
      }

      const finishLog =
        typeof onFinish === "string" ? onFinish : onFinish(result);
      console.log(finishLog);
    }

    return result;
  }

  return logged;
}
```

The difference between sync and async functions is a return type, so both are handled at return stage (and only when `onFinish()` provided).
Generators are trickier because they return the `Generator` instance which depends on its own generics, therefore the generic signature for generator functions is not compatible with sync/async functions. And using this decorator on generator functions is basically logging a `constructor()` call in classes, a feature only seldom useful. But to go beyond that requires runtime method patching of the returned generator, which is way out of scope of this decorator.
So I guess decorators are not supported.